# Shimano Sora vs higher range brake pull ratio

Tags: brakes, shimano

I've just upgraded my commuter bike (old Trek 370) to the replaced components from my main road bike (originally [2009 specialized allez](http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2009&brand=Specialized&model=Allez+Triple) - new head and handle) and found the brake calipers aren't long enough (similar to [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6689/brake-callipers-not-long-enough-to-allow-adjustment-of-pads)). They are unbranded calipers anyway so I'm looking to upgrade them.

Looking at [these](http://www.ribblecycles.co.uk/sp/road-track-bike/brakes-brakes-road-shimano-r451-57mm-brake-set/shimbrar343) long reach calipers I've found they state

> Must be used in conjunction with ST-4600, ST-4603, ST-5700, ST-5703, - ST-6700 or ST-7900 STIs for correct leverage ratio

As far as I can see these are Tiagra and above. I'm not sure which the Allez's shifters were (ST-3500?). What difference is there in lever ratio? I thought all shimano shifters were compatible and can't find any more details about compatibility.

Which calipers can I look at to work with my shifters?

Answer (score 4):

The cable pull ratio was changed for the listed models, whereas previous generations were compatible with a wide range of Shimano and non-Shimano brake components.

Use Shimano's Specifications site to compare the compatibility of your levers and brake calipers.
http://productinfo.shimano.com/specifications.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I can't find any reference to pull ratio. Matching the compatibility of the calipers and the 'Brake lever spec' of shifters shows there are no long reach calipers I can use. Am I reading it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

See the comments on this [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20295/use-of-shimano-long-reach-calipers-with-new-super-slr-brake-levers-shifters). On an old compatibility chart, Shimano says they will play nice with old brake levers, but on newer ones they say they the braking force may be much too high on their data sheets.

However, other companies make decent long reach calipers as well, such as the Tektro R556/R559 (maybe these are *extra* long reach by some people standards, and R539 may be long enough).